Can appspec.yml contain more than 1 lambda?

Here is my example appspec.yml, but when I deploy on CodeDeploy it causes error to appspec.yml can contain only 1 lambda. My scenario is using 1 CodeDeploy action in 1 CodePipeline stage.
